# Cannot install ubuntu or Xubuntu. Screen hangs on splash screen. MSI Ghost Pro

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, nomodeset

I am trying to install Linux onto my new MSI Ghost Pro GS60 6QE computer (I only found out today that MSI is notoriously unreliable with linux) and I am having a lot of trouble. For the whole day I tried to troubleshoot it but to no avail, my situation is this.

I am trying to dual boot my computer with linux using the YUMI pendrive. To get the computer to even recognise the bootable drive I disabled Secure Boot, Fast Boot, Intel Virtualization Technology and Intel Speedstep and also changed "Boot mode select" to Legacy mode.

When I actually run the Ubuntu installer it stalls on the splash screen, when I press escape it shows some process have been completed but seems to freeze on a random process (Eg. in one case it was "Starting Cups ..." and another time it was "Starting WPA"). This happened with all the distros I tried (Xubuntu 15.10, 15.4, 14.4 and Ubuntu 15.10 15.4).

As I am using Yumi and not in grub I don't have access to boot options using f6, all I could do was edit the executable and just replaced "splash screen ---" with "nomodeset ---" and it made no difference other then not loading the splash screen but still stalling on a random process.

My Specs are:

Processor: Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz 2.59 GHz
Motherboard: Microstar International MS-16H7

I hope someone has run into something similar and can help. If there is anyway to pinpoint the error could someone explain.

Thanks for taking the time, it's been a long day.

L.

Comment: Are you willing to use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) instead of YUMi?

Comment: I tried Rufus, it was much faster at building the bootable drive and meant I didn't have to change to legacy mode however the installation still hung at the splash screen. This time I even tried Fedora 23 along with the previous isos. I think it must be a hardware issue.

Comment: OK. There is one thing you can try, similar to `nomodeset`. Highlight the Try Ubuntu option in the installer GRUB menu and press `e`. Put `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the line beginning with `linux` and press `F10`.

Comment: Oh wow it worked. Thank you so much. It went through to the live environment and I hope it works from here. Well at least I have some room to trouble shoot. Thanks again. Can I give you points even though it was a comment?

Comment: I'll just put it as an answer.

Comment: hmmm even though it gets to the desktop as soon as I click anything the system freezes, is there a known fix to this? Is all this due to the new skylake processors?

Comment: Use both the `nouveau.modeset=0` and the `nomodeset` flags and see what happens.

Comment: Okay it is working now (though resolution is messed up though I think I can restore later) and I can access the install ubuntu executable. Thank you again, this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of YUMI, use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie). It's a lot faster and you'll be able to use UEFI.

When you get to the installer GRUB menu, highlight the "Try Ubuntu" option and press <kbd>E</kbd>. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the line beginning with `linux`. [Also set the `nomodeset` flag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu). Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Install Ubuntu and reboot. When presented with GRUB, follow the above procedure to boot into Ubuntu. Once booted, install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers by searching for the Additional Drivers app. Use that to select a proprietary driver, then hit `Apply` and reboot. You shouldn't need the flags again.

Comment: This was really enlightening to read. I was unaware of prereleases or the dangers of Leacy mode, i was just trying something that seemed to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Working for GP62 6QE Leopard Pro. Had enable CSM mode from BIOS

Answer (score 0):

I see you've found an answer; however, I want to point out some of the reasons you had problems, in the hopes of helping you and/or others avoid them in the future....

> I am trying to install Linux onto my new...

Be aware that new hardware often requires the *very newest* OS version, or even not-yet-released software. With the release of Ubuntu 16.04 less than a week away, trying the latest pre-release version might have been worthwhile. (In the future, 16.10, 17.04, and later may be the pre-release versions worth trying, of course.)

> I am trying to dual boot my computer with linux using the YUMI pendrive.

The last I checked, YUMI was 100% useless for creating EFI-bootable disks. The vast majority of new computers boot Windows in EFI mode, and when dual-booting, it's important to install Ubuntu in the same boot mode (BIOS or EFI) as the original OS. Thus, YUMI is 100% useless for most new installations. Don't use it. Use Rufus, Unetbootin, `dd`, or something else instead.

Also, be aware that there are sometimes machine-specific quirks and interactions with the tools used to prepare boot disks, and sometimes with particular settings in these tools. Thus, you may need to try two or three programs, or play with the settings, before you find something that works.

> To get the computer to even recognise the bootable drive I disabled Secure Boot, Fast Boot, Intel Virtualization Technology and Intel Speedstep and also changed "Boot mode select" to Legacy mode.

Some of those changes (like disabling Fast Boot) are helpful. Disabling Secure Boot *should not* be necessary, and doing so increases your risk of contracting a pre-boot virus, so I recommend re-enabling Secure Boot. The biggest issue here was enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support. This action enables booting in BIOS mode, which is the only way you'd be able to boot a YUMI-created disk, so it may seem like a helpful workaround; however, it greatly complicates the boot path and increases the odds of installing the OS in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. In fact, with a YUMI-created disk, it more-or-less *guarantees* a cross-mode installation, which in turn will create new problems down the line -- problems that will be harder to overcome than the problem of booting the installer! Thus, enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support, assuming you want to dual-boot with a pre-existing EFI-mode Windows, is almost certainly a big mistake. For more on this topic, see [my Web page about it.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

One more point: In addition to the EFI's "fast boot" option, there's an option in Windows called Fast Startup, and another called Hibernate. These ***MUST*** both be disabled if you're to safely dual-boot. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for information on doing so. Failing to do this can lead to filesystem corruption and occasionally to damage to boot loaders, and thus to strange boot problems.